# Gatling - How can I ramp up all users to a certain point in a scenario, wait till all got there and continue all at once?

Tags: gatling

I have a simulation where I have to make sure that all users have ramped up to a certain point in my scenario and only than continue (all users at once) 
and execute the rest of the scenario. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it is to use [.rendezVous](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/) at the part of 
the scenario you want all users to reach before continuing.